# drop_duplicates not dropping the duplicate records of the same dtype object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

I have following dataframe:

DF1:

```
col1  |   col2   |  col3
1          2          3
4          5          6
40        50         60
```

when I print the dtypes of this columns, all of them are objects.
Now, I want to add new row(input as dataframe), so I am concatenating those dataframe

DF2:

```
col1  |   col2   |  col3
40        50         60
```

When I print dtypes of the second dataframe its Int64 for all columns, so I convert the second dataframe to object type(as it is possible that second dataframe could have 'str' dtype as well),
so I did the following:

```
DF2 = DF2.astype(DF1.dtypes.to_dict())
DF1= pd.concat([DF1, DF2])
```

And then I concatenate those two dataframes, and after that when I am trying to drop duplicates, it is not dropping the duplicate records

```
DF1 = DF1.drop_duplicates(
            subset=DF1.columns.to_list(), keep='last')
```

Result that I am currently getting:

DF1:

```
col1  |   col2   |  col3
1          2          3
4          5          6
40        50         60
40        50         60
```

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong,

**It works if I convert both dataframe to str dtypes, but that will not be a generic solution I am looking for**

Answer (score 0):

You need convert all columns in both dataframes to a common data type before concatenating them. For example:

```
DF1 = DF1.astype(str)
DF2 = DF2.astype(str)
DF1 = pd.concat([DF1, DF2])
```